# How to add a combo box when a check box is selected?

Tags: java, actionlistener, jcombobox, jcheckbox

I'm trying to have an action listener add a combo box to a control panel when only when a check box is selected. For example, the project I'm currently working on is a t-shirt order form. A check box for "Graphic" is available. When "Monogram" is checked, a combo box "Graphic Style" should appear. How can I go about doing this? Nothing I've tried so far has worked.

Here is my method for building the checkbox

```
public JPanel createGraphicCheckBox()
{
    graphicCheck = new JCheckBox("Graphic");

    ActionListener listener = new MyListener();
    graphicCheck.addActionListener(listener);

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();

    //add check box to panel
    panel.add(graphicCheck);

    panel.setBorder(new TitledBorder(new EtchedBorder(), "Graphic"));

    return panel;
}
```

Here is my method for building the combo box

```
public JPanel createGraphSelectComboBox()
{
    graphSelectBox = new JComboBox();

    //Fills graphics combo box
    graphSelectBox.addItem("Select Graphic");
    graphSelectBox.addItem("AB20");
    graphSelectBox.addItem("JM17");
    graphSelectBox.addItem("PJ23");
    graphSelectBox.addItem("TR16");
    graphSelectBox.addItem("JK52");
    graphSelectBox.setEditable(true);

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();

    panel.add(graphSelectBox);

    return panel;
}
```

And here is my class for my listener

```
class MyListener implementes ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
      if(e.getSource() == monoCheck)
        {
            if(monoCheck.isSelected())
            {
                JPanel comboBoxPanel5 = createGraphSelectComboBox();

                controlPanel.add(comboBoxPanel5);

                revalidate();
            }
        }
     }
 }
```

Thank you guys for all the help you provide!

Comment: And what is happening right now? Why are you wrapping your combobox into additional panel? This can be a problem as no layout manager is set for that panel and nobody knows what will happen. Did you tried to remove that additional panel?

Comment: implements is spelt wrong, probably not the problem though

Comment: you're checking for `e.getSource() == monoCheck`, while the checkbox is called graphicCheck?

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the JCheckbox when the program starts, and then you can set an actionlistener over your "Monogram"-Checkbox for example Mouse Clicked or Mouse Pressed. Then in this actionlistener you can enable your JCheckbox. The code for disable an enable a JCheckbox is:

Enable:

```
your_checkbox.setEnabled(true);
```

Disable:

```
your_checkbox.setEnabled(false);
```

Example:

```
if(monogram_checkbox.isSelected()){
    your_checkbox.setEnabled(true);
} else {
    your_checkbox.setEnabled(false);
}
```